# What is the SQL query in SQLite for filling a table of foreign keys referring to other primary keys respectively

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

In a **SQLite** database I have a **Tasks** table

| task_id | task_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2D |
| 2 | 3D |

a **Codes** table

| code_id | code_name | for_2D | for_3D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | code2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | code3 | 1 | 1 |

and a table to fill **code_task**

| code_id | task_id |
| --- | --- |

In the last two columns of Code table, 1 represents true and 0 represents false. I want to write the sql to fill the **code_task** table with code_id where 2D or 3D column has value 1 and task_id of "2D" and "3D". So the idea result should be

| code_id | task_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

I make such design so that I only need to update **code_task** table if the relationship between task and code gets modified.

Could someone help me with the sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `INNER JOIN` with two conditions applied to the columns for_2D and for_3D :

```
SELECT code_id, task_id
FROM Codes c
INNER JOIN Tasks t ON ( c.for_2D = 1 AND t.task_name = '2D' )
                      OR ( c.for_3D = 1 AND t.task_name = '3D');
```

Results :

```
code_id task_id
1       2
2       1
3       1
3       2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WNyAzWoT)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I made a mistake that's why I cannot figure it out
The SQL I think should be

```
INSERT INTO code_task (code_id, task_id)
SELECT Codes.code_id, Tasks.task_id
FROM Codes
JOIN Tasks ON (Codes.for_2D=1 and Tasks.task_name="2D");
```

I forgot the "()" in the last line previously.